# gcc compiling error: member of nested class A in template class Table is not visible in nested friend class. Why?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, nested, mingw

I am trying to compile some code in mingw32 on windows XP and I got an error. So, I have write a simplified version of that code and got same error. 
Here it is:

```
template <class T>
class Table
{
public:

    class A
    {
    private:
        int nEntry;
        friend class B;
    };

    class B : public A
    {
    public:
        void Remove()
        {
            nEntry = 1;
        }
    };
};
```

Compiler error message:

```
E:\cbProjects\projects\1\main.cpp||In member function 'void Table<T>::B::Remove()':|
E:\cbProjects\projects\1\main.cpp|24|error: 'nEntry' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

Where I can read the items why it's so? (links will be usefull - it may be happen that some other similar errors or compiler bags can appear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a template, member access must sometimes be preceded by an explicit `this->`, as in this case.  You can make your code work this way:

```
this->nEntry = 1;
```